# gl_MultiTexCoord0 not allowed in vert shader in cocos2d v2 alpha?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, shader

I'm trying to use to gl_MultiTexCoord0 in the main of my .vert shader, but the shader won't link with no descriptive error.  Removing the reference to gl_MultiTexCoord0 results in no error.  Is this not supported?  Is there a known workaround?

This is on cocos2d v2 alpha for the iPhone.

Comment: To ask this another way:  Is there another way to do gl_MultiTexCoord0  without using a gl_* call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no gl_MultiTexCoordN in OpenGL ES (like lots of other built-in variables), so you have to pass the texture coordinates as an attribute:

```
    glVertexAttribPointer(texture_id, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, texture_coords_ptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texture_id);
```

To receive readable diagnostics from your shader you have to get an error using the [glGetShaderInfoLog](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml).